# Extending range of wireless network with cable

Tags: wireless-networking, cable

I have a few rooms in my house.

Walls are horribly blocking the wireless signals.

I don't want to go against the physics, so I was thinking that I have ethernet cables in each room, why not extend the wireless range with them? :)

**But**: What "feature" should I search for when buying the networking devices, that support this kind of range extension?

I mean I would buy 2 wireless routers, one is for serving over wireless, and the other one would be connected via ethernet cable to the first serving router and then serving wireless. In this way (thanks to the ethernet cable) there would be 2 wireless routers serving one SSID in two different rooms (connected to each other via cable).

I googled for "mesh" networks, but maybe those are for "only wireless", not "via cable, then wireless".

Comment: you should go for wireless extenders (less trouble)

Comment: Are you saying that you already have Ethernet cables in place? If not, I suggest a power-line extender. If the cabling is already done, then what you need is an Access Point, or a router that can be configured as an AP. In this way DHCP requests for IP configuration will all be handled by your existing router and devices will all be on the same network. I use power-line APs, but I had obscure problems with using the same SSID, and I found it better to give each AP its own SSID, which won't stop devices switching, but you will see which WiFi you're connected to.

Comment: Go with the wireless mesh network. They work exactly like you described and are the best technology to use. Check out CloudTrax. Almost zero config needed on your end. -1 on the comment about using wireless extenders. That’s the absolute worst choice, those things are complete garbage.